# Discard changes made to my forked Postman collection

Tags: postman

**Context:**

1. Fork Workspace **A**'s collection **A1** into Workspace **B**. We will refer to the Forked collection as **B1**
2. Make a change to a request in **B1** for testing purposes.
3. Make a change to that same request but in **A1** (improvements, for example).

**Issue:**

There is no way to reset collection **B1**'s request, back to collection **A1**'s request.

The options available only seem to allow you to merge changes from **B** into **A**?

**Question:**

Am I missing something? I want to discard changes made in my forked collection - **B**. Pulling just notifies me that there are changes, but gives me no way of discarding anything I've modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way of discarding changes on a forked collection** at this current point in time.

As a **work around**, **do not save changes directly to requests**. Instead, **hit Save As** and **then Add "(M)"** (M for Modified. Or B for Bob. Or D for ... different) **to the beginning of the request's name** to distinguish that this one, is one that has been edited.

**This will allow the pull functionality to** continue to **function correctly**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. My temporary workaround is to go into the changelog for B1 and revert to the last time I merged from A1 then pull in the changes